# How to add custom bundle to Wellcommerce?

Tags: symfony

Is there someone who work with Wellcommerce and can help me how to add custom bundle? I try `generate:bundle` but it is not working.

Comment: Try asking a specific question with more details & code!

Answer (score 0):

I am also using this great solution and to answer your question this is what you need to do:

- generate a normal Symfony bundle by using the following command:

  ```
  php app/console generate:bundle WellCommerce\Bundle\CustomBundle
  ```
- alter app/config/routing.yml to not include the routing.yml of the new generated bundle
- inlcude into

  ```
  WellCommerce\Bundle\AppBundle\Resources\config\routing.yml
  ```

  your CustomBundle routing.yml
- clear cache and your new bundle is registered